# How to create a table in flutter without any lines in between the rows?

Tags: flutter, datatable, flutter-table

I need to display a table of data without any lines in between the rows. [I have a table like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMacb.png)

Comment: Show us the code

Answer (score 0):

try to use **GridView** or **Table** Widget